# Yii make submit disabled when post is processing

Tags: validation, yii

Is any way to do it with Yii framework: make submit disabled, after validating success and sending form to server?
I need it to stop multi submitting (double, tripple clicking on submit button).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this functionality is not built in to the CActiveForm code by default.

I just tackled this problem, actually, and ended up having to override CActiveForm to use a custom version of `jquery.yiiactiveform.js`. I thought about rolling it up into an extension, but it's pretty custom so it would be tough, and I'd have to re-release it with every new Yii release if they change `jquery.yiiactiveform.js` *at all*.

After seeing your post here, I did just file an enhancement request with Yii:
http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=2924

Attached to that request is the code I wrote if you want to try and use it yourself.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I hope Yii's developers will integrate this functionality in future.

Comment: How to implement those files into my project?

Comment: Put them in an extension folder called NoSubmit (or something), and when you call your form widget (biginWidget) call it with 'ext.NoSubmit.ActiveForm' instead of 'CActiveForm'